# LC3 simulator continues past end?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am using McGraw-Hill's LC3 simulator to work on some LC3 assembly code. For some reason, no matter how I do my code it continues past my .END call and ends up changing my registers. Am I missing something?

Most recent code:

```
.ORIG x3000

BR MAIN

;;value to square
SquareVal .FILL x04


MAIN   
    LD R1, SquareVal 
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, R1  
    AND R3, R3, #0
    LD R3, SquareVal
    BR SQUARE_CONT

SQUARE_VAL  
    ADD R0, R0, R1
    BR SQUARE_CONT  


SQUARE_CONT 
    ADD R3, R3, #-1
    BRp SQUARE_VAL
    HALT

.END
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your simulator has the operating system code loaded. `HALT` is a system trap so it needs the OS. Furthermore, that also means the OS handler will change your registers. If you can't live with that, you can just do an endless loop in user mode (`STOP: BR STOP`)

`.END` only signals the end of the source file, it has no effect on execution.

Comment: You can prevent it from going past your HALT but putting a breakpoint on the instruction. This will prevent the system call.